# Assigning to 'NSLineBreakMode' from incompatible type

Tags: iphone, ios, uilabel, xcode4.6

After updating my xcode 4.5 to 4.6 ....

```
lblMyLable.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
textFieldRounded1.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
```

stops working and its showing incompatible error...They are working good before 2days just before the xcode update.

**P.S:- lblMyLable is a UILabel &
textFieldRounded1 is a UITextField**

**I am using 6.1 IOS sdk**

Comment: Deprecation in action. People always assume the platform vendor is kidding with their deprecation warnings... :)

Answer (score 2):

In iOS 6 you need to use NSLineBreakByWordWrapping.
Instead of:

```
lblMyLable.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
textFieldRounded1.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
```

Use:

```
lblMyLable.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
textFieldRounded1.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
```

---

## Details

> **lineBreakMode**
>
> The technique to use for wrapping and truncating the label’s text.
>   `@property(nonatomic) NSLineBreakMode lineBreakMode;`
>
> **Discussion**
>
> If you are using styled text in iOS 6 or later, assigning a new value
>   to this property causes the line break mode to be applied to the
>   entirety of the string in the attributedText property. If you want to
>   apply the line break mode to only a portion of the text, create a new
>   attributed string with the desired style information and associate it
>   with the label. If you are not using styled text, this property
>   applies to the entire text string in the text property.
>
> This property is in effect both during normal drawing and in cases
>   where the font size must be reduced to fit the label’s text in its
>   bounding box. This property is set to NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail by
>   default.
>
> Important: If this property is set to a value that causes text to wrap
>   to another line, it is a programmer error to set either the
>   adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth or adjustsLetterSpacingToFitWidth property
>   to YES.
>
> Special Considerations
>
> **In iOS 5 and earlier, the type of this property was UILineBreakMode.
>   Availability**
>
> ```
> Available in iOS 2.0 and later.
> ```

---

> **NSLineBreakMode**
>
> These constants specify what happens when a line is too long for its
>   container.
>
> ```
> enum {   
>    NSLineBreakByWordWrapping = 0,   
>    NSLineBreakByCharWrapping,
>    NSLineBreakByClipping,    
>    NSLineBreakByTruncatingHead,   
>    NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail,    
>    NSLineBreakByTruncatingMiddle
>  };
>  typedef NSUInteger NSLineBreakMo
> ```
>
> **Constants**
>
> **NSLineBreakByWordWrapping**
>
> ```
> Wrapping occurs at word boundaries, unless the word itself doesn’t fit on a single line.
>
> Available in iOS 6.0 and later.
>
> Declared in NSParagraphStyle.h.
> ```
>
> **NSLineBreakByCharWrapping**
>
> ```
> Wrapping occurs before the first character that doesn’t fit.
>
> Available in iOS 6.0 and later.
>
> Declared in NSParagraphStyle.h.
> ```
>
> **NSLineBreakByClipping**
>
> ```
> Lines are simply not drawn past the edge of the text container.
>
> Available in iOS 6.0 and later.
>
> Declared in NSParagraphStyle.h.
> ```
>
> **NSLineBreakByTruncatingHead**
>
> ```
> The line is displayed so that the end fits in the container and the missing text at the beginning of the line is indicated by an
> ```
>
> ellipsis glyph. Although this mode works for multiline text, it is
>   more often used for single line text.
>
> ```
> Available in iOS 6.0 and later.
>
> Declared in NSParagraphStyle.h.
> ```
>
> **NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail**
>
> ```
> The line is displayed so that the beginning fits in the container and the missing text at the end of the line is indicated by an
> ```
>
> ellipsis glyph. Although this mode works for multiline text, it is
>   more often used for single line text.
>
> ```
> Available in iOS 6.0 and later.
>
> Declared in NSParagraphStyle.h.
> ```
>
> **NSLineBreakByTruncatingMiddle**
>
> ```
> The line is displayed so that the beginning and end fit in the container and the missing text in the middle is indicated by an
> ```
>
> ellipsis glyph. Although this mode works for multiline text, it is
>   more often used for single line text.
>
> ```
> Available in iOS 6.0 and later.
>
> Declared in NSParagraphStyle.h.
> ```

Please check [**UILabel Class**](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UILabel_Class/Reference/UILabel.html) for more details.
Also check [**UITextField Class**](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITextField_Class/Reference/UITextField.html) for the NSTextAlignment values and details.

Comment: Also, `UITextAlignmentLeft` has been replaced by `NSTextAlignmentLeft`.

Answer (score 1):

They have both been deprecated in iOS 6;

`UILineBreakModeWordWrap` has been replaced by [`NSLineBreakByWordWrapping`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSParagraphStyle_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSLineBreakMode).

`UITextAlignmentLeft` has been replaced by [`NSTextAlignmentLeft`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/NSString_UIKit_Additions/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSTextAlignment)